# How to spawn a process that DOES NOT request admin rights on the machine in c#

Tags: c#, clickonce

I seem to be asking the opposite of everyone else.  I want to spawn a process and NOT have it request admin rights on the machine.

I have 2 executables:
1) Application
2) Updater

The application periodically checks a web service to see if there are any software updates.  If there are, it will spawn the updater .exe and close the current application.

The updater then downloads the files, unpacks and spawns the original process.

Nothing here seems to need admin rights, and yet UAC keeps getting involved.

This is an application that runs on a machine with no keyboard or mouse and I want the update process to run with no user interaction.

Do I have to turn off UAC in order to get this to work, or have I got something enabled that I need to disable?

I think the only other piece to add here is that I'm using ClickOnce to deploy a minimal app initially that will always run the updater and download the latest copy of the program.

I'm using the following lines to spawn the updater or the calling app:

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("AppUpdater.exe"))
 {
   Process.Start(fileName: "AppUpdater.exe", arguments: appId + " " + versionNo + " " + callingApp);
 }


 if (File.Exists(CallingApp))
 {
   Process.Start(CallingApp);
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: does the app you are launching have a manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my executable for the updater application that was causing the issue.  I had to change some settings in the project properties.

I'm not sure exactly which one was causing the issue because I changed a number of settings to match another application that didn't cause the UAC message to be displayed.

I suspect the main one was the "Icon and Manifest" setting; I changed this to "Embed manifest with default settings".